# Ruby aggregation with objects

Tags: ruby, aggregate

Lets say I have something like this:

```
class FruitCount
   attr_accessor :name, :count

   def initialize(name, count)
     @name = name
     @count = count
   end
 end

 obj1 = FruitCount.new('Apple', 32)
 obj2 = FruitCount.new('Orange', 5)
 obj3 = FruitCount.new('Orange', 3)
 obj4 = FruitCount.new('Kiwi', 15)
 obj5 = FruitCount.new('Kiwi', 1)

 fruit_counts = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5]
```

Now what I need, is a function `build_fruit_summary` which due to a given `fruit_counts` array, it returns the following summary:

```
fruits_summary = {
  fruits: [
    { 
      name: 'Apple',
      count: 32
    },
    {
      name: 'Orange',
      count: 8
    },
    {
      name: 'Kiwi',
      count: 16
    }
  ],
  total: {
    name: 'AllFruits',
    count: 56
  }
}
```

I just cannot figure out the best way to do the aggregations.

Edit:

In my example I have more than one count.

```
class FruitCount
   attr_accessor :name, :count1, :count2

   def initialize(name, count1, count2)
     @name = name
     @count1 = count1
     @count2 = count2
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ruby's Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html) is your friend, particularly [each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) which is a form of [reduce](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce).

You first need the `fruits` value:

```
fruits = fruit_counts.each_with_object([]) do |fruit, list|
  aggregate = list.detect { |f| f[:name] == fruit.name }

  if aggregate.nil?
    aggregate = { name: fruit.name, count: 0 }
    list << aggregate
  end

  aggregate[:count] += fruit.count
  aggregate[:count2] += fruit.count2
end
```

UPDATE: added multiple counts within the single fruity loop.

The above will serialize each fruit object - maintaining a count for each fruit - into a hash and aggregate them into an empty `list` array, and assign the aggregate array to the `fruits` variable.

Now, get the total value:

```
total = { name: 'AllFruits', count: fruit_counts.map { |f| f.count + f.count2 }.reduce(:+) }
```

UPDATE: total taking into account multiple count attributes within a single loop.

The above `map`s the `fruit_counts` array, plucking each object's `count` attribute, resulting in an array of integers. Then, `reduce` is getting the sum of the array's integers.

Now put it all together into the summary:

```
fruits_summary = { fruits: fruits, total: total }
```

You can formalize this in an OOP style by introducing a `FruitCollection` object that uses the `Enumerable` module:

```
class FruitCollection
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(fruits)
    @fruits = fruits
  end

  def summary
    { fruits: fruit_counts, total: total }
  end

  def each(&block)
    @fruits.each &block
  end

  def fruit_counts
    each_with_object([]) do |fruit, list|
      aggregate = list.detect { |f| f[:name] == fruit.name }

      if aggregate.nil?
        aggregate = { name: fruit.name, count: 0 }
        list << aggregate
      end

      aggregate[:count] += fruit.count
      aggregate[:count2] += fruit.count2
    end
  end

  def total
    { name: 'AllFruits', count: map { |f| f.count + f.count2 }.reduce(:+) }
  end
end
```

Now pass your `fruit_count` array into that object:

```
fruit_collection = FruitCollection.new fruit_counts
fruits_summary = fruit_collection.summary
```

The reason the above works is by overriding the `each` method which `Enumerable` uses under the hood for every `enumerable` method. This means we can call `each_with_object`, `reduce`, and `map` (among others listed in the enumerable docs above) and it will iterate over the `fruits` since we told it to in the above `each` method.

Here's an article on [Enumerable](https://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/).

UPDATE: your multiple counts can be easily added by adding a total attribute to your fruit object:

```
class FruitCount
   attr_accessor :name, :count1, :count2

   def initialize(name, count1, count2)
     @name = name
     @count1 = count1
     @count2 = count2
   end

   def total
     @count1 + @count2
   end
end
```

Then just use `fruit.total` whenever you need to aggregate the totals:

```
fruit_counts.map(&:total).reduce(:+)
```

Comment: But there you are adding each FruitCount to the list and I want to aggregate that also by the fruit name. Take a look at the result in the example. I have manage to do it with a single inject, looking in each iteration for the fruit I want to add to its count, but I still want a simpler way.

Comment: Great answer. A couple small improvements: 

1) `fruit_counts` doesn't need `each_with_object` since `@fruits` is already an array/enumerable: `map { |fruit| { name: fruit.name, ... } }`. 

2) You can avoid two runs of the loop and simplify `total`: `count: reduce(0) { |total, fruit| total + fruit.count }`.

Comment: Notice in the example, that I will have multiple FruitCount's for each fruit such as 'Orange'...I want to aggregate also by fruit name, please look at the example. I believe the hardest thing here is to solve it with the less runs. BTW I really like how the answer was explained

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde Ah yes, I see you're maintaining the total count for each fruit within the fruits array. I've adjusted the code to exactly match your example.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by saying that `each_with_object` "is a form of" `reduce`. In any event, it's just a distraction, so I suggest you remove the reference to `reduce`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I meant that `each_with_object` is very much like `reduce`, and the latter tends to be more familiar to developers from across languages.

Comment: I like the answer, but I forgot to say that in the real example, I have more than one count, I will edit my question so you can see the difference. It is really important, because if I have count1, count2, count3, doing this: count: map(&:count).reduce(:+) I will go through the array 3 times

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde just have 1 count map for each count attribute you want to count. e.g. `count2: map(&:count2).reduce(:+)`

Comment: Yeah I know I can, in that way I would go through the whole array more times than the needed. I would like to run the loop once, and in each iteration calculate the 3 counts for example.

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde just add more count lines within the `each_with_object` block. Add more of these: `aggregate[:count2] += fruit.count2`. This will let you do multiple counts within a single loop of the fruits array.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot that is not the problem, `total` is.  def total
    { name: 'AllFruits', count: map(&:count).reduce(:+) }
  end

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde ah yes, that total. Easy change, updated the code.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot sorry I wasn't clear! For `total` I need to return each `count` separately. For example total: { name: 'All', count1: 24, count2: 32}

Comment: @IgnacioVillaverde Ok that's enough, I think you can figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: I understand that you don't want to keep answering this, actually I had a solution before asking the question, the thing was that I wanted to know if there was any better solution. Actually you ended up with a solution similar to mine. Thanks and sorry for bothering!

Answer (score 0):

```
fruits_summary = {
  fruits: fruit_counts
    .group_by { |f| f.name }
    .map do |fruit_name, objects|
      {
        name: fruit_name,
        count: objects.map(&:count).reduce(:+)
      } 
  end,
 total: {
   name: 'AllFruits',
   count: fruit_counts.map(&:count).reduce(:+)
 }
}
```

Not very efficient way, though :)

UPD: fixed keys in `fruits` collection

Or slightly better version:

```
fruits_summary = {
  fuits: fruit_counts
    .reduce({}) { |acc, fruit| acc[fruit.name] = acc.fetch(fruit.name, 0) + fruit.count; acc }
    .map { |name, count| {name: name, count: count} },
  total: {
    name: 'AllFruits',
    count: fruit_counts.map(&:count).reduce(:+)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
counts = fruit_counts.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|obj, h| h[obj.name] += obj.count}
  #=> {"Apple"=>32, "Orange"=>8, "Kiwi"=>16}

fruits_summary =
  { fruits: counts.map { |name, count| { name: name, count: count } },
    total: { name: 'AllFruits', count: counts.values.reduce(:+) }
  }
  #=> {:fruits=>[
  #      {:name=>"Apple",  :count=>32},
  #      {:name=>"Orange", :count=> 8},
  #      {:name=>"Kiwi",   :count=>16}],
  #    :total=>
  #      {:name=>"AllFruits", :count=>56}
  #   }
```